Oracle APEX - page monitoring background dbms_scheduler job
I have a procedure which is taking time to execute. The procedure is being called from Oracle APEX upon clicking on a submit button, but it times out after 30 mins. Since the users doesn't want to push this job to run in background, I decided to see if it's performance can be improved.
So, I thought of doing PARALLEL execution. However, I am getting an error message as ORA-29491: invalid table for chunking ORA-06512: at "XX_WFM.XXMWC_WFM_FRINGES. staging_fringe_data is a global temporary table.
DB is Oracle 19c
PROCEDURE recalculate_fringe_spread(
  p_budget_year_id IN xx_wfm_salary_distribution.budget_year_id%TYPE
)
IS
  l_scope      insum_error_log.scope%TYPE := 'RECALCULATE_FRINGE_SPREAD';
  l_parameters insum_debug.tab_param := insum_debug.tab_param();
  l_task_name  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'RECALCULATE_FRINGE_SPREAD_TASK';
BEGIN
  insum_debug.append_param(l_parameters, 'P_BUDGET_YEAR_ID', p_budget_year_id);
  insum_debug.log_start(l_scope, NULL, l_parameters);
  -- Check if the staging table exists, create it if not
  -- Populate staging table
  INSERT INTO staging_fringe_data
  SELECT b.rate_type,
         b.fb_account,
         a.alternate_allemployee_rate,
         a.alternate_medicare_rate,
         a.alternate_irs_limit,
         d.id AS chunk_id
    FROM xx_wfm_fringe_benefit a
    JOIN xx_wfm_fringe_benefit_dtl b ON b.fringe_benefit_id = a.id
    JOIN xx_wfm_salary_distribution d ON d.budget_year_id = a.budget_year_id
                                       AND d.natural_account BETWEEN b.from_account AND b.to_account
                                       AND d.fund BETWEEN b.from_fund AND b.to_fund
   WHERE d.budget_year_id = p_budget_year_id;
  COMMIT;
  -- Create task
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task(l_task_name);
  -- Create chunks by COLUMN
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_NUMBER_COL(
    task_name     => 'RECALCULATE_FRINGE_SPREAD_TASK',
    table_owner   => 'XX_WFM',
    table_name    => 'STAGING_FRINGE_DATA',
    table_column   => 'CHUNK_ID',
    chunk_size    => 1000
  );
  -- Define SQL statement for parallel execution
  DECLARE
    l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    l_sql_stmt := 'BEGIN
                     xx_wfm_budget.spread_fringe_benefit(
                       p_salary_distribution_id => :chunk_id,
                       p_fringe_natural_account => :fb_account,
                       p_spread_type           => :rate_type,
                       lv_alternate_allemployee_rate  => :alternate_allemployee_rate
                       lv_alternate_medicare_rate     => :alternate_medicare_rate
                       p_cap_limit             => :alternate_irs_limit
                     );
                   END;';
                   
    -- Run task
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(
      task_name      => l_task_name,
      sql_stmt       => l_sql_stmt,
      language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
      parallel_level => 5
    );
  END;
  -- Drop task
  DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task(l_task_name);
  -- Cleanup staging table
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE staging_fringe_data';
  insum_debug.log_end(l_scope, NULL, l_parameters);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    insum_debug.log_error(p_text   => SQLERRM,
                          p_scope  => l_scope,
                          p_params => l_parameters,
                          p_app    => COALESCE(v('APP_ID'), NULL));
    DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.drop_task(l_task_name);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE staging_fringe_data';
    RAISE;
END recalculate_fringe_spread;```


Change the global temporary table to a regular table. Global temporary tables are visible to all sessions, but their data is visible to only one session at a time. Parallel processing uses multiple child sessions, and those child sessions would not be able to see the relevant data from that global temporary table.

Here is an example of how to monitor a background job on the page. This page allow starting of a job that runs for 15 seconds and will display a "running" region when job is running and a "completed region" when job is completed.
I would suggest you implement everything below until it is working, only then apply to your environment. Should be 21.1 proof.
Page Items
For debugging, use type "Text Field", for production, use "Hidden"

P291_JOB_STATE: Page item used to monitor the job state
P291_JOB_NAME: Page item to store job name (needs to be session specific to not clash with other users' jobs)

page items computations

P291_JOB_STATE: Before Regions, Type "Static Value", Value "INIT", Server-side Condition: "Item is NULL", Item P291_JOB_STATE. This computation sets the default value when job doesn't exist yet.

P291_JOB_NAME: Before Regions, Type "Expression", PL/SQL Expression 'JOB_'||:APP_SESSION. This computation sets the unique job name


Page Regions

Region "Buttons" to hold page buttons
Region "Job is Running",

static id "jobrunning",
advanced > custom attributes "style="display:none;" (this will hide region on page load without flickering)


Region "Job Completed",

static id "jobrunning",
advanced > custom attributes "style="display:none;" (this will hide region on page load without flickering)



For the last 2 I used a region with template "Alert".
Page > Execute when Page Loads
Check job every 2 seconds. Change to your needs.
const jobInterval = () => {
    if (apex.item( "P291_JOB_STATE" ).getValue() == 'RUNNING'){
        $.event.trigger("checkjob");
        console.log('checkjob');
    }
};

setInterval(jobInterval, 2000);

Page Buttons
In region "Buttons", add 2 buttons:

START_JOB, Action: Submit Page
RESET, Action: Submit Page

Page Processes
Process "Run Job". This process schedules and runs the job. For this example it's a job that sleeps for 15 seconds.

Server-side Condition: When button pressed: START_JOB
Code:

DECLARE
    l_job_action VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_job_name VARCHAR2(100) := :P291_JOB_NAME;
BEGIN
    l_job_action := 
q'!BEGIN
dbms_session.sleep(15);
END;!';
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name    => l_job_name,
        job_type    => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action  => l_job_action,
        enabled     => true,
        auto_drop   => true);
    :P291_JOB_STATE := 'RUNNING';     
END;

Process "Clear Cache". This process resets the page.

Server-side Condition: When button pressed: RESET
Type: Clear Session States > Clears all Items on the Current Page

Dynamic Action
Action fires on js custom event that is triggered by the interval defined above:

Action 1: Execute Serverside Code
Check status of job

Action 2: Execute Javascript Code
Set spinner on the "Job is Running" region.

Source:

if (lSpinner$) {
    lSpinner$.remove();
}
var lSpinner$ = apex.util.showSpinner( $( "#jobrunning" ) );


Client-side Condition Item=Value; P291_JOB_STATE Value RUNNING

Action 3: Execute Javascript Code
Remove spinner on the "Job is Running" region.

Source:

var lSpinner$ = apex.util.showSpinner( $( "#jobrunning" ) );
lSpinner$.remove();


Client-side Condition Item=Value; P291_JOB_STATE Value COMPLETE

Action 4: Show

Region: "Job is Running"
Client-side Condition Item=Value; P291_JOB_STATE Value RUNNING

Action 5: Show

Region: "Job Completed"
Client-side Condition Item=Value; P291_JOB_STATE Value COMPLETE

Action 6: Hide

Region: "Job is Running"
Client-side Condition Item=Value; P291_JOB_STATE Value COMPLETE

Action 7: Hide

Region: "Job Completed"
Client-side Condition Item=Value; P291_JOB_STATE Value RUNNING


This is what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed steps. However, I get this error in opening and closing the region - Uncaught Error: Error: Region does not support being opened and closed.

There is no "Open Region" in my example. Maybe you picked "Open Region" instead of "Show" and "Close Region" instead of "Hide" ? Check the inline help, "Open Region" is only supported by a limited nr of specific regions and is not applicable here. Try using "Show" and "Hide" as actions.

You state "the users doesn't want to push this job to the background". Well... you could execute a the job in the background anyway. At the UI side create a page with a region of type "dynamic content" that shows "processing... please wait" that is refreshed every x seconds until the job is completed. That way it would run as a job in the background - so it doesn't time out, but the user would perceive it as a running on the fly. This will be a much easier solution.

We are on APEX 21.2. Does it work on this? Do you have any examples of that? Thank you!
